# Undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: kolebro in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/includes.php on line 12
```

**function.php**

```
public function User_Details($uid) 
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT uid, username, sansiti, kolebro AS full_name FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid' AND status = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    return $data;    
}
```

**includes.php**

```
$session_data = $Wall->User_Details($uid);
$session_sansiti = $session_data['sansiti']; // <== Line 12
$session_kolebro = $session_data['kolebro'];
```

**index.php**

```
<?php echo $session_kolebro; ?>
<?php echo $session_sansiti; ?>
```

Can anyone help me understand (what is causing) this error?

Comment: Notice (not an error) says exactly what is going on - your `$session_data` array does not have any value under `kolebro` key.

Comment: `var_dump($session_data)` to see the content

Comment: I think you function doesnt work since it doesn`t have a connection included.

Comment: Mihai it's ext/mysql rather than mysqli, so the last connection opened is used regardless of scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're retrieving the database field `kolebro` using the alias `full_name` – so `$session_data` won't have a `kolebro` index, it'll have one called `full_name` instead.

- Either change `$session_data['kolebro']` to `$session_data['full_name']`
- Or remove `AS full_name` from the MySQL query.

---

Also, [**please don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).